# How to merge two object of an array into one?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api, object

I want to modify json file.In this question i have submitted required information.
Here the controller part..

```
    $questionLimit=$questions->count();
    $response=[];
    for($i=0;$i<$questionLimit;$i++){
       $response[$i]=[
        'question_with_choice'=>$questions[$i],
        'candidate_chosen_ans'=>$quizSessionAns[$i]
       ];
    }
    return response($response);
```

The output of the above code is given below..

```
[
{
    "question_with_choice": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "which is the prime number?",
        "image": null,
        "config": "1",
        "question_type": "Multiple Quesiton",
        "choices": []
    },
    *"candidate_chosen_ans": 2*
}    
]
```

But my expected output will be like...

```
 {
    "question_with_choice": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "which is the prime number?",
        "image": null,
        "config": "1",
        "choices": []
        "candidate_chosen_ans": 2
    },
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, create new key to `$questions['candidate_chosen_ans']`

```php
$questionLimit=$questions->count();
$response=[];
for($i=0;$i<$questionLimit;$i++){
    $questions['candidate_chosen_ans'] = $quizSessionAns[$i];
    $response[$i]=[
    'question_with_choice'=>$questions[$i],
    ];
}
return response($response);
```